# Why loadInitTopStory method called after calling loaded state in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, bloc

HackerNewsLoadedState is called before HackerNewsLoadingState and it loads all data from API but does not integrate to _topStories list as well as store data to _topstories after calling HackerNewsLoadedState.

```
 @override
  Stream<HackerNewsState> mapEventToState(HackerNewsEvent event) async* {
    if (event is FetchHackerNewsEvent) {
      yield HackerNewsLoadingState();

      try {
        _loadInitTopStories();
        yield HackerNewsLoadedState(story: _topStories);
      } catch (e) {
        yield HackerNewsErrorState(message: e.toString());
      }
    }
  }
  void _loadInitTopStories() async {
    try {
      _topStoryIds.addAll(await _repository.loadTopStoryIds());
    } catch (e) {
      _topStoriesStreamController.sink.addError('Unknown Error');
      return;
    }

    loadMoreTopStories(pageSize: INIT_PAGE_SIZE);
  }

void loadMoreTopStories({int pageSize = PAGE_SIZE}) async {
    if (_isLoadingMoreTopStories) return;

    _isLoadingMoreTopStories = true;
    final storySize = min(_currentStoryIndex + pageSize, _topStoryIds.length);
    for (int index = _currentStoryIndex; index < storySize; index++) {
      try {
        _topStories.add(await _repository.loadStory(_topStoryIds[index]));
      } catch (e) {
        print('Failed to load story with id ${_topStoryIds[index]}');
      }
    }
    _currentStoryIndex = _topStories.length;
    _topStoriesStreamController.sink.add(_topStories);
    _isLoadingMoreTopStories = false;
  }
```

Comment: You need provide more details of code, the best would be provide code that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: update my code please check it

Comment: why  `HackerNewsLoadedState is called before HackerNewsLoadingState` ?

where's init of _topStories ?

Comment: but when I used without method calling it works me

Comment: do you use bloc ?

I suggest you provide more code, a code which can reproduce.

Comment: I used bloc. [code link](https://ideone.com/8XPlyH)

Comment: you didn't define `_isLoadingMoreTopStories` in your code.

Comment: according to your code,  HackerNewsLoadedState is must call after HackerNewsLoadingState.

Comment: you need to found out why HackerNewsLoadingState call after HackerNewsLoadedState.

Comment: _isLoadingMoreTopStories is assigned but still not working. how can I HackerNewsLoadingState call first?

Comment: please debug first. it's impossible for me to debug your current code. base on your code.

Comment: @JerryZhou found the solution it's return void but it's a mistake, it returns Stream<HackerNewsState>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution it's return void but it's a mistake, it returns Stream

```
  Stream<HackerNewsState> _loadInitTopStories() async* {
    yield HackerNewsLoadingState();
    try {
      _topStoryIds.addAll(await repository.loadTopStoryIds());
    } catch (e) {
      _topStoriesStreamController.sink.addError('Unknown Error');
      return;
    }
    yield* loadMoreTopStories(pageSize: INIT_PAGE_SIZE);
    yield HackerNewsLoadedState(story: _topStories);
  }

  Stream<HackerNewsState> loadMoreTopStories(
      {int pageSize = PAGE_SIZE}) async* {
    if (_isLoadingMoreTopStories) return;

    _isLoadingMoreTopStories = true;
    final storySize = min(_currentStoryIndex + pageSize, _topStoryIds.length);
    for (int index = _currentStoryIndex; index < storySize; index++) {
      try {
        _topStories.add(await repository.loadStory(_topStoryIds[index]));
      } catch (e) {
        print('Failed to load story with id ${_topStoryIds[index]}');
      }
    }
    _currentStoryIndex = _topStories.length;
    _topStoriesStreamController.sink.add(_topStories);
    _isLoadingMoreTopStories = false;
  }
```